# MvvmCross - Internationalization with Store App's FlyOut

Tags: xaml, internationalization, windows-store-apps, mvvmcross, flyout

I'm using MvvmCross with my Store App. The internationalization technique explained by Stuart Lodge works very well, but I have a little problem with FlyOuts. It seems that 'sometimes' (I haven't found the reason yet) the first time a FlyOut appears, it shows the fallback values, while it works good the following times.
Has anyone already faced this problem?
Here my AppBarButton:

```
<AppBarButton Icon="Delete" >
    <Button.Flyout>
        <Flyout>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock mvx:Bi.nd="Text TextSource, Converter=Language, ConverterParameter=DeleteConfirm, FallbackValue=You are about to delete this item Fake"
                    Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" />
                <Button mvx:Bi.nd="Content TextSource, Converter=Language, ConverterParameter=Delete, FallbackValue=DeleteFake" 
                    Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Flyout>
    </Button.Flyout>
</AppBarButton>
```

Comment: Sorry. I think some more investigation might be needed on when "sometimes" is - otherwise it's too hard to guess.

Comment: The problem is the very first time the flyout shows, in particular in a page with a large number of controls.
In a more simple page I saw the "fallback values" only once. Unfortunately I didn't understand the real reason and the workaround was to define properties in the ViewModel that return the needed translations, and to use them in binding in the standard way. I'm ready to do further debug if someone has suggestions